# JavaScript add error message to character counter for html form?

Tags: javascript

I have created a character counter for a textarea field on a form in an HTML page.  I have a separate .js file to validate fields like name, Email, etc.  I need to COMBINE my new code that validates if a user typed over 140 characters into my current validate.js file.  Below is part of my HTML form, new code, validation, counter, and helper function.  If I add my new code to my validation.js, it does not work.  How do I combine the two?  Thank you for those that help.

HTML FORM

```
<label for="comments">Comments&#58;</label><span id="comment-count" class="hide"></span>
<br>
<textarea name="comments" id="comments" rows="4" cols="40"></textarea><br>
<span id="comments.error"></span><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit"/>
</fieldset>
<script src="utilities.js"></script>
<script src="counter.js"></script>
<script src="validate.js"></script>
</form>
```

NEW CODE

```
var comment = document.forms["contactform"]["comments"].value;
var count = document.getElementById('comment-count'); 
var countError = document.getElementById('count');
var valid = count.value.length <= 130;
if (!valid) 
{
countError.innerHTML = "test";
ret = false;
}
else
{
countError.innerHTML = "";
}
```

validate.js

```
function validateForm()

{
var ret = true;
var name = document.forms["contactform"]["name"].value;
var nameError = document.getElementById('name.error');
if (name == "") 
{
nameError.innerHTML = "Please enter your name";
ret = false;
} 
else 
{
nameError.innerHTML = "";
}
var email = document.forms["contactform"]["email"].value;
var emailError = document.getElementById('email.error');
var valid = /[^@]+@[^@]+/.test(email);
if (!valid) 
{
emailError.innerHTML = "Please enter a valid Email";
ret = false;
} 
else 
{
emailError.innerHTML = "";
}
var type = document.forms["contactform"]["service"].value;
var serviceError = document.getElementById('service.error');
if (document.getElementById('service').selectedIndex == "")
{
serviceError.innerHTML = "You must select a service";
ret = false;
}
else 
{
serviceError.innerHTML = "";
}
var comments = document.forms["contactform"]["comments"].value;
var commentsError = document.getElementById('comments.error');
if (comments == "")
{
commentsError.innerHTML = "Please provide a description";
ret = false;
}
else 
{
commentsError.innerHTML = "";
} 
return ret;
}
```

CHARACTER COUNTER

```
(function ()

{
var comment = document.getElementById('comments');
var commentCount = document.getElementById('comment-count');

addEvent(comment, 'focus', updateCounter);
addEvent(comment, 'input', updateCounter);

addEvent(comment, 'blur', function ()
{
if (comment.value.length <=140)
{
commentCount.className = 'hide';
}
});

function updateCounter(e)
{
var target = e.target || e.srcElement;
var count = 140 - target.value.length;
if (count < 0)
{
commentCount.className = 'error';
}
else if (count <=15)
{
commentCount.className = 'warn';
}
else
{
commentCount.className = 'good';
}
var charMsg = '<b>' + count + '</b>' + ' characters';
commentCount.innerHTML = charMsg;
}
}());
```

HELPER FUNCTION

```
function addEvent(el, event, callback)

{
if ('addEventListener' in el)
{
el.addEventListener(event, callback, false);
}
else
{
el['e' + event + callback] = callback;
el[event + callback] = function()
{
el[event + callback](window.event);
};
el.attachEvent('on' + event, el[event + callback]);
}
}
```

Comment: not technically what you've asked, but thought it might be useful:  you can use maxlength attribute to set maximum number of characters in a textarea (thus not needing to write everything on your own)

Comment: And that goes on my HTML form, correct?  Thank you.